# Displaying an image in elm view

Tags: html, web, elm

I'm having a lot of issues displaying images in elm. Whenever I do something like this, I would get this error 
[image].

```
view : Model -> Html Msg  
view model =
        [img [src  "Img1.png"], width 300, height 300 ]
```

What I want to give a Html Msg that will display an image posx 0 posy 0 width 300 height 300 source "./Img1.png"

Answer (score 5):

You have some brackets in the wrong place and a missing `[]` at the end. The code should be:

```
view model =
    img [src "Img1.png", width 300, height 300] []
```

So there's no `[` the start because you need to return an HTML node, all the attributes go in in the second list, and there should be an empty list at the end for `img` elements.

Comment: Thanks for the help! How would I add the x and y position of the image in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by x and y position? Can you give an example of the HTML you want?

Comment: This isn't html code but you can get the idea of what I want from this <img src="smiley.gif" width="42" height="42" x = 0px, y = 110px>

Comment: Well this library generates HTML nodes. `<img>` doesn't support any `x` or `y` attributes.